# MySQL Getting a count on two parameters

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table of orders, which contains a little over 200 million records. For statistics, I need to get three different counts. The first is the number of orders placed within a certain date range, then the number of orders placed from a specific state, and finally the number of orders from a specified state during a certain date range. The first two queries return 10-20 million records on average, and usually take under five seconds. However, I have not been able to get the third query to return results in under an hour. Here are the actual queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```

The above has 10 mil records to summarize, query takes 4 seconds.

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id 
    WHERE customer.state = 'PA';
```

The above has 15mil records to summarize, query takes 5 seconds.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM orders 
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2) 
UNION 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
    WHERE customer.state = 'PA');
```

The above has 4500 records to summarize, query takes 2 hours.

Is there another approach I can take for that third query that would give me the count in a more reasonable amount of time? Preferably less than a minute?

Comment: Can you please post the table definitions, aswell as EXPLAIN outputs?

Comment: You realize that UNION will remove duplicates -- if both are 25, you'll only see one row.

Comment: Forget about time, the 3rd query is not returning the correct results.

Comment: By "return 10-20 million records" you mean searches 10m records. `COUNT(*)` without a `GROUP BY` will only **return** 1 record.

Comment: What I meant was the count returned was between 10000000 and 20000000. What I am theorizing is that the third operation has to compare that many pieces of data is the reason it is taking so long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join the queries together. Also, change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `INNER JOIN` since you are filtering by the customer state.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM orders 
    INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
WHERE customer.state = 'PA' AND order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 3 queries should be.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2; 

SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id 
     WHERE customer.state = 'PA'; 

SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id 
     WHERE customer.state = 'PA'
       AND order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```

The 2nd one can be a LEFT JOIN, but since you are filtering on customer using a WHERE clause, there is no reason to preserve any records from LEFT JOINing.

For what it's worth, your 3rd query that attempts to return counts from queries 1 and 2 in a single query is working slowly `most likely` because MySQL looks at the UNION And went all funny.  Either of the below should work better

```
SELECT "Date", COUNT(*) 
   FROM orders 
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
UNION ALL
SELECT "Customer", COUNT(*) 
   FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
    WHERE customer.state = 'PA';
```

or

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM orders 
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2) DateCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
    WHERE customer.state = 'PA') CustomerCount
```

(the second one returns it as two columns instead of 2 rows)